# Loading a backup in a freshly linux installation

Tags: linux-mint, backup

Please reference if this question is already answered.

I am doing a backup of my hardrive before installing again Linux. I am doing this process with my dd command. If I reinstall Linux Mint, how can I do to install everything in the home partition?

I suppose that it should be enough to do:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sda1
```

Is this enough, or do I need to do something more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/home-partition.

Comment: If `/home` is a separate partition (or perhaps a RAID array) then just ignore it during system install, and after first boot go in and set it  up again to be mounted in the right space, moving the existing `/home` to `/home-default` or similar

Comment: @Christopher why you think this is not a good tool? I understand that the best option so far is `rsync`, and `copy` is better to avoid it in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is correct, the command you use will copy one partition to another. You can also use files to backup to using DD, that way you can also put some /etc/ files ore something else you want to keep on the same external drive as where you put your home backup.